# Create a graph with these conditions...

Tags: graph-theory

Create a graph G with the following properties:
- G has 7 vertices
- G is bipartite
- It has 12 edges
- It does **not** contain a Hamilton cycle

And create a graph H such that:
- G has 7 vertices
- H has 12 edges
- H contains a Hamilton cycle

For G, my idea is that there should be two sets of vertices, A and B, with |A|=4, |B|=3, and somehow creating a graph satisfying these conditions above?

For H, I've got C7 (cycle with 7 vertices), so do I just add any 5 edges?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE!  Please, consider updating your question with some information about what you've tried and where you are getting stuck.  You will find that the community will be much more willing to help you if you do!

Comment: Ignore the above. You will get help anyway.

Comment: I need help real quick, anyone please!

Comment: P.S. its hard to show my working when I'm trying to draw graphs....

Comment: @Ocambole, I don't agree with your comment. We are not here to do exercises for people but to help them to learn math.

Comment: @Sigur You have just been proven wrong. See below.

Comment: @Ocambole, I know that some one do the job but I believe that it is important to give some ideas and ask the OP to show the effort. An opinion is only an opinion, it can not be wrong.

Comment: Sorry about the change, I forgot to say that the graphs both need 7 vertices only. Sorry! (I have tried to do this for a while so that's why I need help)

Comment: @pj241 Answer updated.

Comment: @Ocambole thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1) For the first part you can put two rows of vertices; one row (call it A) with 4 vertices, the other (call it B) with 3 vertices. Then, draw all the edges that go from the vertices in row A to the vertices in row B. I think this is called the complete bipartite $3,4$ graph $K_{3,4}$.

The graph is not going to have a hamiltonian cycle because:

In the Hamiltonian cycle, in a bipartite graph, in between each vertex from the row A there must be a vertex from row B. This forces the same number of vertices in each row. But that is not the case $3\neq4$.

(2) For the second part put the 7 vertices in a circle. The circle will form the edges of the Hamiltonian cycle. The circle forms 7 edges. So, add another 5 edges anywhere.

Comment: Great, thanks! It was so simple, should have got it myself.. :/

Comment: @pj241 Now next time you will get it yourself. You will remember having seen the idea of Hamiltonian cycle + bipartite = the vertices alternate. Math is 80% experience, 15% discipline in following algorithms, and 5% intelligence.

Answer (score 0):

a) Use 13 vertices and connect the first with all others.

c) A dodecagon

Comment: What if both must have 7 vertices only?

Comment: Note that the question was edited to include extra restrictions a few minutes after you posted this answer.